# What is the first order derivative of the MMSE estimator over the observation?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, parameter-estimation

Consider the observation $y=x+n$, where $n\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and the priori distribution $x\sim p_0(x)$. I know the MMSE estimator is given by $\hat{x}=E[x|y]$. What is derivative of the following
\begin{align}
\frac{d\hat{x}}{dy}=?
\end{align}
I recall there is reference said that $\frac{d\hat{x}}{dy} = {\sigma^2}\text{var}[x|y]$. Is it true? How can we prove it?

Comment: How can the result not be $1$, as $\hat{x} = E[x|y] = E[y + n|y]   = y +E[n|y] = y  + 0 = y$ ?

Comment: What is the meaning of result of 1?

Comment: What I proved above is $$\frac{d\hat{x}}{dy}=1$$
And **not**
$$\frac{d\hat{x}}{dy} = {\sigma^2}\text{var}[x|y]$$